# Salesforce Console Layout how to achieve UI look

Tags: console, ui, lightning-page

I was looking at some old dreamforce recordings and I saw this salesforce console app.

[Here is a link to the recording - they start showing the app at around 12 minutes](https://www.salesforce.com/video/305066/)

My question is how did they achieve the layout shown in the image below. It's extremely clean looking. I've been messing around in the console view and cant seem to achieve something that looks this clean.

Are they using some kind of custom component or has the UI for console apps changed signifigantly since 2016. Any tips to achieve this layout in an app would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You're looking at the Classic Console. The Lighting Console looks different.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I'm gonna assume its best then to forget about this and just use the lightning console. Thank you again I would have never figured that out haha